# Why no warning on cin status ignored but warning on ignoring scanf result?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

g++ compiler warns if you ignore the result of a `scanf` call, but doesn't warn if stream status is not checked after reading using `cin`.

Why is it considered less dangerous to ignore stream status?

Comment: Is it reasonable to compare them?

Comment: For one, a stream can be independently configured to toss an exception on failure. Such a configuration would make checking the return status  of a `std::cin >> val` expression result pointless, as you would never receive it, finding yourself in an exception handler instead. And props for cranking warnings so thick an unchecked `scanf` is flagged.

Comment: BTW, I get no warning on -> `g++ -Wall test.cpp -o t` using cin/scanf, what're you using?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: some warnings are only displayed when you compile with `-O2` because that includes flow analysis. May be that's the problem?

Comment: No, didn't turn out that way. I've tried every -O I've found. But that's with gcc 4.4.7; I'm a couple years out apparently - oh, well.